# How to select all checkboxes from table using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

> Script:-

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#cbSelectAll").click(function () {
                if (this.checked) {
                    $(':checkbox').each(function () {
                        this.checked = true;
                        var selectall = document.getElementsByClassName(".checkBoxClass");
                        var cid = $(this).attr('id');
                        console.log('cid' + cid);
                        var hidSelectAll = document.getElementById("hfSelectAll");
                        var hidCustomer = document.getElementById("hfCustomerID");
                        hidCustomer = '';
                        var str = 'Select All';
                        hidSelectAll.value = str;
                        console.log(hidSelectAll);
                    });
                    $("#GridRows .checkBoxClass").change(function () {
                        if (!$(this).prop("checked")) {
                            $("#cbSelectAll").prop("checked", false);
                            var cid = $(this).attr('id');
                            console.log('cid' + cid);
                            var hidSelectAll = document.getElementById("hfSelectAll");
                            var str = 'Select All + unselected values';
                            hidSelectAll.value = str;
                            console.log(hidSelectAll);
                        }
                    });   
                }
                else {
                    $(':checkbox').each(function () {
                        this.checked = false;
                        var hidSelectAll = document.getElementById("hfSelectAll");
                        var str = 'UnSelect All';
                        hidSelectAll.value = str;
                        console.log(hidSelectAll);
                    });
                    $(".checkBoxClass").change(function () {
                        if (!$(this).prop("checked")) {
                            $("#cbSelectAll").prop("checked", false);
                            var hidSelectAll = document.getElementById("hfSelectAll");
                            var str = 'unSelect All + selected values';
                            hidSelectAll.value = str;
                            console.log(hidSelectAll);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

> HTML:-

```
<body>
        <h4>Number Of Records - <span>@ViewBag.ItemCount</span> </h4>
        <div class="table-responsive" style="padding-left:20%;">
            <table class="table-fill" style="float:left;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-left">                            
                             Select All
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <input style="margin-left:15px;" type="checkbox" id="cbSelectAll" />
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-left" style="padding-left:27px;">
                            First Name
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-left" style="padding-left:32px;">
                            Last Name
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-left" style="padding-left:40px;padding-right: 60px;">
                            Email-ID
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-left" style="padding-left:30px;padding-right: 40px;">
                            Customer Type
                        </th>
                        <th class="text-left" style="padding-left:15px;">
                            Customer Designation
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
            <div id="GridRows" style="width:65%;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="pager"></div>
        <input type="hidden" id="currentPage">
        <input type="hidden" id="hfCustomerID"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="hfSelectAll" />
    </body>
```

this is html. Rows generated dynamically from jquery ajax call to avoid loss of values stored in hidden field on page load.

> In this when clicked on select all checked box all values of table
>   from same page selected.
>
> how to store all values of table from multiple pagination when clicked
>   on Select All checkbox?
>
> what are option for storing all values of table?

Comment: Can you please add the HTML code of the page

Answer (score 1):

Actually your checkAll(..) is hanging without any attachment.

1) Add onchange event handler

2) Modified the code to handle check/uncheck

```js
function addRow(tableID) {

     var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

     var rowCount = table.rows.length;
     var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

     var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
     var element1 = document.createElement("input");
     element1.type = "checkbox";
     element1.name = "chkbox[]";
     cell1.appendChild(element1);

     var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
     cell2.innerHTML = rowCount;

     var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
     cell3.innerHTML = rowCount;

     var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
     cell4.innerHTML = rowCount;

     var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
     cell5.innerHTML = rowCount;

     var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
     cell6.innerHTML = rowCount;
 }

 function deleteRow(tableID) {
     try {
         var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
         var rowCount = table.rows.length;

         for (var i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
             var row = table.rows[i];
             var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
             if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                 table.deleteRow(i);
                 rowCount--;
                 i--;
             }
         }
     } catch (e) {
         alert(e);
     }
 }

 function checkAll(ele) {
     var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
     if (ele.checked) {
         for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
             if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                 checkboxes[i].checked = true;
             }
         }
     } else {
         for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
             console.log(i)
             if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                 checkboxes[i].checked = false;
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

```html
<INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" />
<INPUT type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('dataTable')" />
<TABLE id="dataTable" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <INPUT type="checkbox" onchange="checkAll(this)" name="chk[]" />
        </th>
        <th>Make</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Start Year</th>
        <th>End Year</th>
    </tr>
</TABLE>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can if you are using datatable.

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    stateSave: true
});

var allPages = oTable.fnGetNodes();

$('body').on('click', '#selectAll', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('allChecked')) {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]', allPages).prop('checked', false);
    } else {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]', allPages).prop('checked', true);
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('allChecked');
})
});
```

There is one more option i.e. you have to add same class name on all checkboxes and add this code.(If you not use datatable).

```
var select_all = document.getElementById("select_all");
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox"); 
select_all.addEventListener("change", function(e){
    for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = select_all.checked;
 }
});

for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', function(e){ //".checkbox" change
//uncheck "select all", if one of the listed checkbox item isunchecked
    if(this.checked == false){
        select_all.checked = false;
    }
if(document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox:checked').length ==checkboxes.length){
        select_all.checked = true;
    }
});
}
```